# Selecting rows by datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is probably fairly easy but suppose I have the following data frame with Datetime index:

```
 DateTimeIndex  Val_1   Val_2
    1995-01-11  461.66  0.0
    1995-01-12  461.64  0.0
    1995-01-13  465.97  1.0
    1995-01-16  469.38  1.0
    1995-01-17  470.05  1.0
    1995-01-18  469.72  1.0
    1995-01-19  466.95  1.0
```

I would like to loop through the data frame and select the subsequent row after the row where val_2 == 1, in this case, that should 4th row (1995-01-16  469.38  1.0)

```
col_name = 'Val_2'    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[col_name] == 1:
       # select subsequent row
       # do sth else
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: `df[df['Val_2']==1]` to select all rows with `Val_2 == 1`. `df[df['Val_2'].shift()==1]` to select all rows with `Val_2 == 1` **except** the first one.